# How to get and compare 2 similar position points in different DXF file?

Tags: autocad, dxf

We have 2 similar reinforcement drawing DXF files. One is standard, other is need to be compared. They have similar position points and a bit of different values.
We want to compare them.
The question is :
How to get the same position point data from 2 DXF file?
And How to ensure they are same?

Welcome to any suggestions, solutions~

Thanks.

Comment: Please reformulate your question, I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I assume you are referring to POINT objects ? If so, you will have to parse those POINT objects into two lists. Then you can identify the ones from list B close to each in list A. If I understand you right.